# Testing with gorm and sqlmock

Tags: go, go-gorm, go-sqlmock

I am struggling with writing a test for my go lambda function with sqlmock and gorm.

This is the function I want to test:

```
func DoCleanup(con *gorm.DB) {
    sixMonthsAgo := time.Now().AddDate(0, -6, 0).Format("2006-02-01")
    con.Where("date_to <= ?", sixMonthsAgo).Delete(&Availability{})
    con.Where("date_to <= ?", sixMonthsAgo).Delete(&Reservation{})
}
```

And this is my test:

```
func TestDoCleanup(m *testing.T) {
    var mock sqlmock.Sqlmock
    var db *sql.DB
    var err error

    db, mock, err = sqlmock.New()
    assert.Nil(m, err)

    dialector := mysql.New(mysql.Config{
        DSN:                       "sqlmock_db_0",
        DriverName:                "mysql",
        Conn:                      db,
        SkipInitializeWithVersion: true,
    })

    conn, err := gorm.Open(dialector, &gorm.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        m.Errorf("Failed to open connection to DB: %v", err)
    }

    if conn == nil {
        m.Error("Failed to open connection to DB: conn is nil")
    }

    defer db.Close()

    mock.ExpectQuery(fmt.Sprintf("DELETE FROM availability WHERE date_to <= '%s'", time.Now().AddDate(0, -6, 0).Format("2006-02-01")))
    mock.ExpectQuery(fmt.Sprintf("DELETE FROM reservations WHERE date_to <= '%s'", time.Now().AddDate(0, -6, 0).Format("2006-02-01")))

    DoCleanup(conn)

    err = mock.ExpectationsWereMet()
    assert.Nil(m, err)

}
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong. This is the first time I'm using sqlmock. I've read up a few places, and my code looks fine, but I'm not getting the results. My error is:

```
Expected nil, but got: &errors.errorString{s:"there is a remaining expectation which was not matched: ExpectedQuery => expecting Query, QueryContext or QueryRow which:\n  - matches sql: 'DELETE FROM availability WHERE date_to <= '2022-13-06''\n  - is without arguments"}
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your code expects nanoseconds to be exactly the same, try mocking time.

Comment: I changed it so that it uses another format, and it still fails. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the main problem I see is around the way you are expecting the Query to be. Instead of

```golang
    mock.ExpectQuery(fmt.Sprintf("DELETE FROM availability WHERE date_to <= '%s'", time.Now().AddDate(0, -6, 0).Format("2006-02-01")))
```

you should have:

```golang
    mock.ExpectBegin()
    mock.ExpectExec("DELETE FROM `availability` WHERE date_to <= ?").
        WithArgs(time.Now().AddDate(0, -6, 0).Format("2006-02-01")).
        WillReturnResult(sqlmock.NewResult(0, 0))
    mock.ExpectCommit()
```

This will tell the mocking that you are using a transaction (`ExpectBegin` and  `ExpectCommit` around the delete, that the query was made with an argument(`WithArgs`), and what the return of the query will be (`WillReturnResult`)

There are some other minor changes, like the `` around the table name (a MySQL idiom) and the name of the table (gorm will typically pluralize names so either you implemented `TableName` on `Availability` or it will default to availabilities).

The best way for you to see all these problems would be to change the `DoCleanup` to return errors and then look at them on the test:

```golang
func DoCleanup(con *gorm.DB) error {
    sixMonthsAgo := time.Now().AddDate(0, -6, 0).Format("2006-02-01")
    tx := con.Where("date_to <= ?", sixMonthsAgo).Delete(&Availability{})
    if tx.Error != nil {
        return tx.Error
    }
    tx = con.Where("date_to <= ?", sixMonthsAgo).Delete(&Reservation{})
    if tx.Error != nil {
        return tx.Error
    }
    return nil
}
...
    err = DoCleanup(conn)
    assert.Nil(m, err)
...
```

Doing this, and with the current code you would get

```
Expected nil, but got: &errors.errorString{s:"call to database transaction Begin, was not expected, next expectation is: ExpectedQuery => expecting Query, QueryContext or QueryRow which:\n  - matches sql: 'DELETE FROM availability WHERE date_to <= '2022-13-06''\n  - is without arguments"}
```

This tells you that sqlmock was not expecting a Begin, after solving that you will get the other errors that are resolved in the first part of this answer.

Comment: Thank you. So a few extra changes were necessary, but this solved the issue.